# php ftp functions response messages

Tags: php, ftp, response

Is it possible with `php` FTP to get or retrieve the welcome message the server sends?

Something like this you get from FTP clients

> Status:   Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>
> **Response:   220 Welcome to the OpenDreambox FTP service.**

Plus is it possible to get the response code like 220 in that case?
Are they even FTP standards those codes?

Comment: The codes are standard, clients actually use them to determine a command's response, not the text after the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with the ftp_* functions, but there's an alternative approach:

```
$socket = fsockopen("ftp.microsoft.com", 21); 
echo fgets($socket); //read the welcome line
fclose($socket);
```

Comment: so I have to make a separate fsockopen connection to get this message ans still use the FTP functions?

Comment: That's the best solution I found. This additional socket lives for only a very short time, so it shouldn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [ftp_raw](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-raw.php),

This function `Returns the server's response as an array of strings. No parsing is performed on the response string, nor does ftp_raw() determine if the command succeeded.`

Comment: problem is that this needs a resource link as first parameter and the welcome message is returned with OPEN hostname:port which that function can't perform